# Restrict input to a specified language

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

I use a **TextInput** component of Flex 4.5 to enter some text in English. I use the ***restrict*** attribute to ... restrict the keyboard input to characters a-zA-Z only. The problem is that if i copy/paste a word in another language, i can then paste it into the TextInput component. Is there a way to avoid that? If no, how can i validate the input against a specified language?

I found out that the unicode set of Chinese+ language symbols is \u4E00 to \u9FFF. So i write the following:

```
var chRE:RegExp = new RegExp("[\u4E00-\u9FFF]", "g");
if (inputTI.text.match(chRE)) {
  trace("chinese");
}
else {
  trace("other");
}
```

But if i type in the TextInput the word 'hello' then it validates...What is the error?

Since i cannot (my fault? or a bug?) use unicode range with RegExp, i wrote the following function to check if a word is in Chinese and that's it.

```
private function isChinese(word:String):Boolean
{
    var wlength:int = word.length;
    for (var i:int = 0; i < wlength; i++) {
            var charCode:Number = word.charCodeAt(i);
            if (charCode <= 0x4E00 || charCode >= 0x9FFF) {
                    return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Validate on change for the characters you want?

Comment: actually yes ... i have implement something, it was very simple with text.match("_regex"), but i'm having a hard time to validate simplified chinese (which is the language that i want to validat :)

Comment: Then you need to determine the char set that chinese use. Sorry I can't help with that I don't speak greek.

Comment: ...chinese is the language...

Comment: I don't speak German either :)

Comment: Have a look at this link  It might help you validate some characters. http://www.google.com/#hl=en&sugexp=pfwc&cp=9&gs_id=8&xhr=t&q=gb18030+characters&qe=R0IgMTgwMzAg&qesig=baKKI_HULlNDwovdWw_DZg&pkc=AFgZ2tlYaT65IO-4_eRI0aEYKdPf9lrM7BRDGJilm5vWpbrnwb7Ab4rImvcerOaAjXSU2MX_UVasc_1au3EWmANSWD-RRUmdww&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&safe=off&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=GB+18030+&aq=0sx&aqi=g-sx4&aql=f&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=b083820506f29980&biw=1320&bih=804

Comment: "how can i validate the input against a specified language?" I'm not sure how advisable this is... I don't know what you're wanting to do with the input or how many languages you want to "detect", but it would be very difficult to say with any certainty that a string is in a particular language, especially only using a regular expression.

Comment: why? in case of just a simple word, i think the only required rule is to check each character of the word if belongs to the given set of primitives symbols of the language..do i miss some cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `String.match()` method returns an array which will always test to true, even if it's empty (see docs here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#match%28%29)

Use the `RegExp.test()` method instead to see if it matches:

```
// Check your character ranges:
//var chRE:RegExp = new RegExp("[\u4E00-\u9FFF]", "g"); // \u9FFF is unrecognised and iscausing issues.
var chRE:RegExp = new RegExp("[\u4E00]+", "g"); // This works.
if (chRE.test(inputTI.text)) {
  trace("chinese");
}
else {
  trace("other");
}
```

You'll need to check the character ranges too - I couldn't get it to match with \u9FFF in the regex.

Comment: yes that approach is the correct, thanks! But still have problem specifying the unicode range in regex...