# Specifying a unicode range in an actionscript regular expression

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

I have been trying to write a regular expression that would match all unicode word character something like :

```
/[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF\w]/gi
```

But this completely fails and doesn't match anything. I have tried a variety of expressions and it seems that as soon as I try to specify a range it fails. As anyone been luckier than me?

I wish actionscript would offer something like \p{L}, but if there's anything in the like, I couldn't find it in the doc.

Answer (score 3):

You can use String.fromCharCode with the unicode characters and then the ranges will work correctly in a regular expression.  Here is an example using your original problem:

```
var exp:RegExp = new RegExp("[" + generateRangeForUnicodeVariables(0x00A0, 0xD7FF) + generateRangeForUnicodeVariables(0xF900, 0xFDCF) + generateRangeForUnicodeVariables(0xFDF0, 0xFFEF) + "\w]", "gi");

private function generateRangeForUnicodeVariables(var1:Object, var2:Object):String
{
   return String.fromCharCode(var1) + "-" + String.fromCharCode(var2);
}
```

Comment: I've been searching for a Flash-specific solution for finding unicode hex ranges (for emojis) for quite a while. After trying MANY regexes I'm pleased to report your approach worked perfectly in my implementation. FINALLY.

Answer (score 1):

This has been a problem for sometime and I couldn't find any information that it has been solved, previously asked in:

[Restrict input to a specified language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561916/restrict-input-to-a-specified-language)

and

[How to specify a unicode range in a RegExp?](http://forums.adobe.com/message/3941906)

I know this is a hack, but it does work in JavaScript so you could use ExternalInterface to farm the test out there and pass the result back.

Comment: If you do go down my route, here is a link to help build the regex patterns in Javascript http://kourge.net/projects/regexp-unicode-block

Comment: I hadn't thought of ExternalInterface, it's a very good idea! My current solution is no less of a hack since i just loop through my (short)string, check each character against a whitelist and remove them if they don't match up.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. Looks like it's not about ranges, it's about multi-byte characters.

This works:

```
 var exp:RegExp = new RegExp("[\u00A0-\u0FCF]", "gi");
 var str:String = "\u00A1 \u00A2 \u00A3 \u00A3";
 trace("subject:", str);
 trace("match:", str.match(exp));
```

And this does not:

```
 var exp:RegExp = new RegExp("[\u00A0-\u0FD0]", "gi");
 var str:String = "\u00A1 \u00A2 \u00A3 \u00A3";
 trace("subject:", str);
 trace("match:", str.match(exp));
```

Anyway, you can use RegExp constructor that converts a string to a matching pattern.

Comment: "you can use RegExp constructor that converts a string to a matching pattern" - interesting, can you elaborate?

Comment: Emm... That's what I actually did in my tests with `new RegExp("[\u00A0-\u0FD0]", "gi");`. I don't have any clues though to why ranges don't work as expected for characters with codes over `\u0FCF`.