# RegExp: check for at least one (unicode) character above code point 0x7f

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, unicode, ascii, non-ascii-characters

I'm trying to test whether a string contains at least one (unicode) character above code point `0x7f` (i.e. a non-ascii character).

I've tried the following ideas (and a few others), but they don't seem to work:

```
var rx:RegExp;

rx = /[^\\x00-\\x7f]/; // negate ascii code point 0 to 127
trace( rx.test( '\u0080' ) ); // true (expected true)
trace( rx.test( 'b' ) ); // true (expected false)

rx = /[^\u0000-\u007f]/; // negate unicode code point 0 to 127
trace( rx.test( '\u0080' ) ); // false (expected true)
trace( rx.test( 'b' ) ); // false (expected false)
```

Can somebody help me understand why this is not working as expected and how to do it properly?

Comment: also please look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10414034/specifying-a-unicode-range-in-an-actionscript-regular-expression . I found it very interesting.

Answer (score 2):

```
/[^\\x00-\\x7f]/;
```

The double-backslash means a literal backslash, so you are looking for a character group that excludes backslash, `x`, `0`, all the characters between `0` and backslash, `x`, `7` and `f`.

You would only use double-backslashes if the regex were in a string literal (as in `new RegExp('[^\\x00-\\x7F]')`); pretty much the entire purpose of the regex literal syntax `/.../` is to allow you to type backslash-heavy expressions without the extra layer of escaping.

```
'foo'.search(/[^\x00-\x7F]/)!==-1  // false
'bär'.search(/[^\x00-\x7F]/)!==-1  // true
```

However:

```
rx = /[^\u0000-\u007f]/; // negate unicode code point 0 to 127
trace( rx.test( '\u0080' ) ); // false (expected true)
```

`true` for me in browser JavaScript. If not in ActionScript that would appear to be a non-ECMA-conformant bug.

Comment: The reason I used double-backslashes is because this is [mentioned in the documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ea5.html#d17e6915) (multiple times). Could still be typos off course. I found them strange as well. However, as [I mentioned in this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20341431/regexp-check-for-at-least-one-unicode-character-above-code-point-0x7f#comment30382559_20341691), it appears ActionScript indeed has a bug in that regard. ActionScript doesn't seem to like the `\u0000` character, somehow. `\x00` *does* work though.

Comment: Ugh! That is sad indeed (both the bug and the doc-bug).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if AS3 supports unicode RegExp like, for example, Python does.
I can suggest following solution, that will help you to do what you want, but I'm sure it's slow for long strings.

```
function containsUnicode(text:String):Boolean
{
    for (var i:int = text.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (text.charCodeAt(i) > 127)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: That's a decent alternative, but might get slow for long strings indeed. I think I've solved the problem though. After looking at the other question you suggested, I played around with different ranges, and it appears that `\u0000` was the culprit. When I change the range to `\u0001-\u007f` it works as expected. Perhaps `\u0000` (the `NUL` character) is extant in AS3 strings by default (under the hood, or something. I don't know exactly).

Comment: I'm glad you could solve your problem, it was interesting to know the solution. Why don't you post your own answer to help others with a similar question!